# How to fetch local storage before downloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I made local storage codes for some additions The problem here is that it brings storage after loading the page I want a way to make it faster and come and execute before loading the page and thanks for the help.

```js
var myDirection = "rtl";

setTimeout(function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("BlogLangAr") !== null) {
    BlogLang = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangAr");
    myDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    BlogDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    $("html")
      .attr("lang", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangAr"))
      .attr("dir", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
    $("body").removeClass("ltr").addClass(localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("BlogLangEn") !== null) {
    BlogLang = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangEn");
    myDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    BlogDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    $("html")
      .attr("lang", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangEn"))
      .attr("dir", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
    $("body").removeClass("rtl").addClass(localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("BlogLangFr") !== null) {
    BlogLang = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangFr");
    myDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    BlogDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    $("html")
      .attr("lang", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangFr"))
      .attr("dir", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
    $("body").removeClass("rtl").addClass(localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDe") !== null) {
    BlogLang = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDe");
    myDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    BlogDirection = localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir");
    $("html")
      .attr("lang", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDe"))
      .attr("dir", localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
    $("body").removeClass("rtl").addClass(localStorage.getItem("BlogLangDir"));
  }
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in putting your js code within the `<head>` tag. This way it can run prior to `<body>` being loaded. But this is not always a guarantee.

[This](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded) will also assist you understand the HTML Lifecycle and feasible load events.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help but is there a way to download it before the html document itself ?

Comment: Localstorage is on the browser. And the html document is loaded from the server... So what you're basically saying is that you want to use data from the browser on the server and that is impossible in that respect using localStorage and javascript.